# Overriding search control, contextual scope as default

Tags: 2007, feature, search-scope, xml, contextualscope

I have a strange problem regarding the overriding of search delegate control in SharePoint 2007.
The purpose of why i override it is to set drop down mode to show contextual scopes as default aka first.

So i created a feature which will be activated on scope = web.
And in the control i set ShowDD_DefaultContextual, according to msdn it should show all scopes but the first that will be selected is most actual scope.
So that is what i need.

But the problem is, I can't see in the drop down list the standard scopes like "all sites" and "people". The contextual scopes are selected as promised but lack of ootb search scopes is not accaptable for me.

Here is whole xml definition for the control:

```
  <Control Id="SmallSearchInputBox" Sequence="25" 
           ControlClass="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SearchBoxEx" 
           ControlAssembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">

    <Property Name="GoImageUrl">/_layouts/images/gosearch.gif</Property>
    <Property Name="GoImageUrlRTL">/_layouts/images/goRTL.gif</Property>
    <Property Name="GoImageActiveUrl">/_layouts/images/gosearch.gif</Property>
    <Property Name="GoImageActiveUrlRTL">/_layouts/images/goRTL.gif</Property>
    <Property Name="SearchResultPageURL">/_layouts/osssearchresults.aspx</Property>
    <Property Name="ScopeDisplayGroupName"></Property>
    <Property Name="FrameType">None</Property>
    <Property Name="UseSiteDefaults">true</Property>
    <Property Name="DropDownModeEx">ShowDD_DefaultContextual</Property>

  </Control>
```

Do I miss something?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the solution:

This line from xml should have been deleted:

```
 <Property Name="ScopeDisplayGroupName"></Property>
```

When i delete that line and redeploy, I receive the expected results.
Hope this will help other people.